# Not able to connect to back-end using minikube

Tags: node.js, reactjs, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to deploy an application in minikube locally .
When i start the minikube , I am able to connect to the front-end, but NOT the back end.

Below are the yaml files

Ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/
            backend:
              serviceName: server-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 8080
```

UI-deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: web

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: registry.gitlab.com/test/test1/test2/app-UI
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gitlab-auth
```

UI-service

```
apiVersion: v1
# sets up networking in kubernetes cluster
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  selector:
    component: web
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

backend-deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: registry.gitlab.com/test1/test2/test3/test4-api
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gitlab-auth
```

Backend-Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: server
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

I keep getting the below error on the browser

```
POST https://192.168.99.111/api/auth/login 404
dispatchXhrRequest  @   xhr.js:155
xhrAdapter  @   xhr.js:16
dispatchRequest @   dispatchRequest.js:49
Promise.then (async)        
request @   Axios.js:55
Axios.<computed>    @   Axios.js:74
wrap    @   bind.js:11
(anonymous) @   LoginForm.tsx:34
callback    @   createBaseForm.js:554
(anonymous) @   createBaseForm.js:579
validateFields  @   createBaseForm.js:541
LoginForm.handleSubmit  @   LoginForm.tsx:17
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:147
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:196
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:250
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @   react-dom.development.js:265
executeDispatch @   react-dom.development.js:571
executeDispatchesInOrder    @   react-dom.development.js:596
executeDispatchesAndRelease @   react-dom.development.js:695
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @   react-dom.development.js:704
forEachAccumulated  @   react-dom.development.js:676
runEventsInBatch    @   react-dom.development.js:844
runExtractedEventsInBatch   @   react-dom.development.js:852
handleTopLevel  @   react-dom.development.js:5029
batchedUpdates$1    @   react-dom.development.js:21463
batchedUpdates  @   react-dom.development.js:2247
dispatchEvent   @   react-dom.development.js:5109
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:21520
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:255
interactiveUpdates$1    @   react-dom.development.js:21519
interactiveUpdates  @   react-dom.development.js:2268
dispatchInteractiveEvent    @   react-dom.development.js:5085
```

1)  When i run the app without minikube the application runs fine.
2)  When i run the app with minikube and hit https://192.168.99.111 , the 
    front end comes up fine.
3)  As soon as i try to hit login button and app tries to connect to 
    backend ,  i get the above error.
4)  For some reason its not able to connect to backend when running on 
    minikube and i keep getting resource not found error.

192.168.99.111 is the minikube ip

I am brand new to kubernetes and any help in debugging is highly appreciated.

**Update**

I think its some issue with ingress controller
When i see in ingress controller logs it showed

`192.168.99.1 - [192.168.99.1] - - [10/Jun/2019:00:07:58 +0000] "POST /api/auth/login HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "http://192.168.99.116/auth/login?redirect=/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36" 520 0.001 [default-server-cluster-ip-service-8080] 172.17.0.8:8080 19 0.002 404 702298110b92307929f9817bb50c47ff`

instead of http://192.168.99.116/auth/login?redirect=/, it should have been 
http://192.168.99.116/api/auth/login?redirect=/

Why is `/api` getting dropped?

Comment: i have found the issue. I don' want to do a rewrite

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your ingress configuration.
Your backend application has rule to redirect itself to `/auth/login` path and it can't be solved via Ingress controller if you want to add prefix. You have to configure your backend API to handle those URLs by app code.

Answer (score -1):

This is what `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` do for you. It remove the prefix in your ingress config. You could remove this annotation to keep `/api/` in the path.

See this: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/rewrite